# deciding whether a group homomorphism preserving some properties or not as follows

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-homomorphism

Let $f:G \to H$ be a group homomorphism. Which the statement is true? Why?

1. If $H$ is finite, then so is $G$.
2. If $H$ is finite cyclic, then so is $G$.
3. If $H$ is abelian, then so is $G$.

**Edit:** $f$ isn't trivial group homomorphism.

My attempt:

1. If $G$ is finite, then so is $H$, but not as converse. The converse is hold iff $f$ is injective.
2. Same with point 1) above.
3. Same with point 1) above and let $f(a),f(b)\in H$. Then, $f(a)f(b) = f(b)f(a) \Leftrightarrow f(ab)=f(ba)$. Note that $ab=ba$ is not necessarily true.

Any idea? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I don’t believe your answer for 1 is correct. I can embed Z/2Z into ZxZ/2Z through the homomorphism f(0)=(0,0) f(1)=(0,1).

Comment: @uhhhhidk The answer for all 1 to 3 is wrong, right?

Comment: @uhhhhidk Any argument for every point above?

Comment: @uhhhhidk Or any idea?

Comment: I can’t really tell since the context of two is different than that of one so saying your answer for 2 is 1 doesn’t make sense. But to quickly answer your question, consider the map f: Z->Z/2Z. These are both cyclic groups, one infinite, one finite. Also there are maps from non-cyclic groups to cyclic groups (the projection of Z/2ZxZ/2Z onto Z/2Z)

Comment: for 3 I believe you are correct, if I’m not mistaken there is a map from the quarternions to Z/2Z with kernel isomorphic to Z/4Z. Try to find another example tho

Comment: for 3, Q_8 and its normal subgroup is abelian, right?

Comment: I edited that comment, I realized it didn’t make sense

Comment: All three are false. For 1 and 2, a counterexample is $G = \mathbb Z$, $H = Z / 2\mathbb Z$, and $f$ is the canonical homomorphism $f(n) = n + 2\mathbb Z$. For 3, a counterexample is $G = S_3$, $H = S_3 / A_3$, and $f$ is the canonical homomorphism $f(g) = gA_3$.

Comment: @Bungo For $f(g)=gA3$, it's a group homomorphism since for all $a,b\in S_3, f(a+b)=(a+b)A_3 = aA_3 + bA_3 = f(a) + f(b)$, right?

Comment: What about the trivial group homomorphism? Is it also wrong? How?

Comment: @user795084 You said you wanted to exclude the trivial homomorphism. If we allow $f$ to be trivial, then it's even easier to find counterexamples. For 1 and 2, let $G$ be any infinite group and $H$ any finite cyclic group. For 3, let $G$ be any non-abelian group and $H$ any abelian group.

Comment: @Bungo thanks ${}{}{}$

Answer (score 1):

Remember that there is a trivial group homomorphism between any two groups, namely the function $f\colon G\to H$ defined by $f(g) = e_H$ for all $g\in G$ (here $e_H$ denotes the identity element of $H$).

With this in mind, is there any information about the group $H$ that would give us information about the group $G$?

Comment: Yes, there is. $H$ finite then so is $G$ ?

Comment: If $H$ is finite, is $G$ also finite ?

Comment: What happens if you take $G=\Bbb Z$ and $H=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ in the construction from this answer?

Comment: its wrong, right?

Comment: $f(g)=\bar{0}, \forall g\in G$ ?